# What wrong in my code?

Tags: c++

Adding a node the beginning of linked list. But I have bug. This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ;
struct Node{
 int x;
 struct Node *next;
}
void add_begin(struct Node *a, struct Node *b){
 if( b == NULL ){
  b = a ;     
 }
 else{
  a -> next = b;
  b = a;
 }
}

void showList(struct Node *c){
 while( c != NULL ){
  cout << c->x << endl;   
  c = c -> next ;
 }
}

int main(){
 struct Node *List = NULL ;
 struct Node *first = new ( struct Node ) ;
 struct Node *second = new (struct Node) ;
 first -> next = NULL;
 second -> next= NULL ;
 first -> x = 1;
 second -> x = 2;
 add_begin(first, List);
 add_begin(second, List);
 showList(List);

 return 0 ;
}
```

Output of this code is empty. I think the bug is in the **add_begin** function. But i don't know what's wrong. Any idea ?

Comment: You are passing variable `List` by value, so the local copy in `main` is going to stay `NULL`.

Comment: have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: No need to guess. Debug your program. Print some stuff, or use a debugger.

Comment: I knoew that there would be no aparrent debugging before I opened it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a linked-list problem with, (gasp!), no aparrent debugging done.  Every linked-list question is a debug-slave command, and I'm getting pretty pissed off with them all.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question. OP had made progress, but just missed the pass by value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function `add_begin` you are changing local variable `b` because the argument is passed by value that is the function deals with a copy of the argument. So any changes of the local variable do not influence on the argument.

Write the function the following way

```
void add_begin( Node * &head, int x )
{
    Node *tmp = new Node { x, head };

    head = tmp;
}
```

and call it like

```
add_begin( List, 1 );
add_begin( List, 2 );
```

It is the function that will create new nodes in the list.

If your compiler does not support initializer lists with the new operator then you can rewrite the function like

```
void add_begin( Node * &head, int x )
{
    Node *tmp = new Node;

    tmp->x = x;
    tmp->next = head;

    head = tmp;
}
```

Take into acccount that this syntax used in your code

```
struct Node *first = new ( struct Node ) ;
```

is invalid. Instead you have to write

```
struct Node *first = new struct Node;
```

or simply

```
Node *first = new Node;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `add_begin` function takes its parameters by value. That means the function receives in its scope a copy of the pointers. when you assign `b = a` inside the function, you are assigning to the copy, and the assignment is not visible outside the function. If you pass the pointers into the function  by reference, then the assignment takes place with the referred-to pointers from the calling scope of the function.

Try this:

```
void add_begin(struct Node * & a, struct Node * & b)
{
 if( b == NULL )
 {
   b = a ;     
 }
 else
 {
   a -> next = b;
   b = a;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void add_begin(struct Node *a, struct Node *b){
 if( b == NULL ){
  b = a ;     
 }
 else{
  a -> next = b;
  b = a;
 }
}
```

You just change the pointer b, but not the "List"